# How do I get an animate.css class to apply to all chat bot replies (written in Rivescript) using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, chatbot, animate.css, rivescript

I have written a chatbot script using rivescript and I have integrated a chatbox into my site. When the user inputs text, I want the bot's response text to 'fadeInUp' onto the screen. The javascript i've written works for the initial bot reply (after the page has been refreshed) but when I type another input it appears on screen as normal (just appears without fading in). Here's my code so far -

**HTML**

```
<!-- AI output -->
<div id="ai-out">
    <p id="ai-output"></p>
</div>

<!-- User input -->
<div id="ai-in">
    <input id="user_input"></input>
    <button id="submit"> > </button>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
let button = select('#submit');
let userinput = select('#user_input');
let aioutput = select('#ai-output');

button.mousePressed(chat);

function chat() {
    let input = userinput.value();
    let reply = bot.reply("local-user", input);
    aioutput.html(reply);
    $('#ai-output').addClass('animated fadeInUp');
}
```

Comment: Is the id `ai-output` being repeated?

Comment: If not, I'm assuming nothing is removing the `animated` and `fadeInUp` classes from the element after the first time.  If the classes are already on an element, `addClass` will not add them again.  You will want to remove them at some point before the next message is shown so the animation happens again.

Comment: Ah i'm not that experienced so im struggling here. I bet the solution is obvious but i tried this and it's still the same:  if(button.mousePressed) {$('#ai-output').removeClass('animated fadeInUp');}  Do you have any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: What is the duration of the animation?

Comment: Dummy example of clearing out the classes. https://jsfiddle.net/pdsbkyLq/

Comment: Yes this worked! The setTimeout() method was just what I needed. Thanks for your help.